# Interface Implementation for RecyclerView Android to Click Items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, interface, onclick

I am trying to make a clickable RecyclerView on an Android app. There are no errors in code, but the items in the RecyclerView are not able to be clicked. The items are set to true for "clickable" in the XML code. My guess is that the issue is somewhere in the use of the interface as that is relatively new to me. Thanks for any help.

```
package com.example.localmusic;

public interface OnBandVenueListener {
    void onBandVenueClick(int position);
}
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
package com.example.localmusic;

public class DisplayUserBandsVenues extends AppCompatActivity implements OnBandVenueListener {
private ActionBar actionBar;

private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

private TextView bandOrVenue_textView;
private RecyclerView rvResults;

private Query band_query;
private Query venue_query;

private ArrayList<String> bands = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> venues = new ArrayList<String>();

private String update_band_or_venue;
private String userID;

private UserBandsVenuesAdapter mUserBandsVenuesAdapter;
private OnBandVenueListener mOnBandVenueListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_user_bands_venues);

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF0367BE")));

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser fBUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    userID = fBUser.getUid();

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    band_query = mDatabase.child("bands");
    venue_query = mDatabase.child("venues");

    update_band_or_venue = getIntent().getStringExtra("updateWhat");

    bandOrVenue_textView = findViewById(R.id.select_textView);
    rvResults = findViewById(R.id.bands_venues_recyclerView);

    bandOrVenue();
}

public void bandOrVenue() {
    if(update_band_or_venue.equals("band")) {
        bandOrVenue_textView.setText("Select Band to Update");

        band_query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Band band = child.getValue(Band.class);

                    if(band.getBandAuth().equals(userID)) {
                        String band_name = band.getName();
                        bands.add(band_name);
                    }
                }

                mUserBandsVenuesAdapter = new UserBandsVenuesAdapter(bands, mOnBandVenueListener);
                rvResults.setAdapter(mUserBandsVenuesAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
    else if(update_band_or_venue.equals("venue")) {
        bandOrVenue_textView.setText("Select Venue to Update");

        venue_query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Venue venue = child.getValue(Venue.class);

                    if(venue.getVenueAuth().equals(userID)) {
                        String venue_name = venue.getName();
                        venues.add(venue_name);
                    }
                }

                mUserBandsVenuesAdapter = new UserBandsVenuesAdapter(venues,  mOnBandVenueListener);
                rvResults.setAdapter(mUserBandsVenuesAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        bandOrVenue_textView.setText("Error!");
    }

    rvResults.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}

@Override
public void onBandVenueClick(int position) {
    Intent intent;

    if(update_band_or_venue.equals("band")) {
        intent = new Intent(this, UpdateBandInfo.class);
    }
    else if(update_band_or_venue.equals("venue")) {
        intent = new Intent(this, UpdateVenueInfo.class);
    }
    else {
        intent = new Intent(this, DisplayUserBandsVenues.class);
    }

    startActivity(intent);
}

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
package com.example.localmusic;


public class UserBandsVenuesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserBandsVenuesAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<String> mResults;
private OnBandVenueListener mOnBandVenueListener;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    public TextView bandVenue_name_textView;

    OnBandVenueListener onBandVenueListener;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView, OnBandVenueListener onBandVenueListener) {
        super(itemView);

        bandVenue_name_textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bandVenue_name_txtView);
        this.onBandVenueListener = onBandVenueListener;

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onBandVenueListener.onBandVenueClick(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}

public UserBandsVenuesAdapter(List<String> results, OnBandVenueListener onBandVenueListener) {
    mResults = results;
    mOnBandVenueListener = onBandVenueListener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public UserBandsVenuesAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent,
                                                          int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View userBandsVenuesView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.band_venue_list_item, parent, false);

    UserBandsVenuesAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new UserBandsVenuesAdapter.
            ViewHolder(userBandsVenuesView, mOnBandVenueListener);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserBandsVenuesAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                             int position) {
    String result = mResults.get(position);

    TextView bandVenue_name_textView = viewHolder.bandVenue_name_textView;

    bandVenue_name_textView.setText(result);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mResults.size();
}
```

Display with RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bluemusicoriginal"
tools:context=".DisplayUserBandsVenues">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/select_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="User Bands or Venues"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/bands_venues_recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="409dp"
    android:layout_height="680dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/select_textView" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

List Item XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/bandVenue_list_cl"
style="ListSeparator"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bandVenue_name_txtView"
    android:layout_width="307dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Band or Venue Name"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#c0c0c0"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bandVenue_list_cl" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It looks as though the onClick method isn't getting called.

Comment: That makes sense, because the given code would be crashing with a `NullPointerException` if it made it that far. Are you seeing any visual feedback when you click on an item? Please [edit] your question to show us the `Activity` and `RecyclerView` item layouts.

Comment: Mike M: The problem seems to be that I can click on the item as long as I don't click within the textbox that contains the band or venue name.

Comment: Remove the `android:clickable="true"` and `android:focusable="true"` attributes from that `<TextView>`. That, and sadat's suggestion below, should do it.

Comment: Yep! That did the trick! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change this line

```
mUserBandsVenuesAdapter = new UserBandsVenuesAdapter(venues,  mOnBandVenueListener);
```

to

```
mUserBandsVenuesAdapter = new UserBandsVenuesAdapter(venues,  DisplayUserBandsVenues.this);
```

because you implement that interface into that Activity.

Comment: Apparently the onClick method for the interface is not getting called. I put a debugging test in there and it failed.

Comment: Can you update your code again? Remove this line private OnBandVenueListener mOnBandVenueListener;, because its always null

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Create your interface method in your adapter class

```
    public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(String text, int position);
}
```

Then create a variable of ItemClickListener in your adapter class

```
ItemClickListener mItemClickListener;
```

create an onClickListener Method in your adapter class

```
    public void onClickListener(YourAdapterName.ItemClickListener listener) {
    mItemClickListener = listener;
}
```

Then in the item onclicklistener in the adapter add this

```
   if (mItemClickListener != null) {
            mItemClickListener.onItemClick(mData.get(position).getText(), position);
        }
```

Then make your activity class  implements YourAdapteName.ItemClickListener
And set your adapter on OnclickListener like this

```
yourAdapterName.onClickListener(this);
```

When you have implemented The ItemClickListener you will have to override the onItemClick then you do whatever you want there.